# Bitlocker decryption stuck at 82.1% (No disk activity)

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, bitlocker

> TL;DR: Bitlocker decryption of a 4TB USB HDD stuck at 82.1% with 0% disc activity for hours. No errors found on the drive, files still fully accessible.

I have been decrypting BitLocker on my USB disc drive for the past two days, and I recently noticed that it had been at "82.1% Completed" for hours. Task manager now shows 0% disc activity for the drive, whereas before it was 100% (for the past two days).

- Drive: 4TB (USB HDD drive) Bitlocker (full) encrypted, auto-unlock nabled. Recovery key working.
- Main usage: Backups
- Unique information on the drive: 1TB of data not backed up anywhere else
- Windows version: 10 Pro 64-bit 1909
- Bitlocker version: 2.0
- USB port: 3.0

**What I have tried:**

1a. Pausing and resuming BitLocker

1b. Rebooting the machine and trying again

1c. Booting into safe mode and trying again

1d. Booting into recovery mode (X:\ administrator command prompt) and using "manage-bde"

1e. Disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS and trying again

1f. Enabling CSM in the BIOS and trying again

1e. Using "manage-bde" to pause, resume, start encrypting and then start decrypting again (on steps 1b, 1c, and 1d).

1f. Connecting the drive to another Windows 10 Pro 64-bit computer and trying steps 1a and 1e.

1g. Running "chkdsk" in an administrator command prompt, and via the GUI version in drive properties, both said no errors were found.

1h. Attempting to use "repair-bde F: G: -rp [Full recovery password, that has been tested and is working] -Force", however I don't have another drive that is 4TB capacity (the "G" drive is a 32GB USB stick). Output:

```
Bitlocker Drive Encryption: Repair Tool version 10.0.18362

Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

LOG ERROR: 0xc000003d

Needs at least 3815318 MB of free space for repair.

ERROR: Not enough free space on output volume to perform repair.
```

**What I have observed:**

1. 30-60% disc activity on the drive for about a second on steps 1a, 1b, 1c,
2. 100% disc activity on the drive when using "manage-bde -on F:" (re-encrypting the drive)
3. 100% disc activity on the drive when using "manage-bde -off F:" (decrypting the drive again) AFTER step 2, but only until (I assume) BitLocker gets to the same place where it was stuck before, as disc activity drops to 0%. This leads me to believe that BitLocker may be getting stuck in a particular place or on a particular file.

I still have full access to the drive and can read/write perfectly fine. Have successfully viewed files, added files and removed files (for testing). I can read/write perfectly fine on both Windows machines I tested on.

I have already contacted an "IT Pro/Admin" from Microsoft Support who guided me with steps 1e and 1f, but BitLocker still appears to not be doing a lot.

I have also looked at the BitLocker event logs, but nothing about errors is displayed, simply status messages such as

> BitLocker decryption was started for volume F:.

and

> The BitLocker protected volume F: was unlocked. Protector GUID: `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}` Identification GUID: `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

If you have any ideas or suggestions for fully decrypting the drive, please let me know.

Comment: Are any of the files unencrypted? Windows is wonky sometimes on updating progress, I have seen it report a certain percentage and freeze at that number when the task has actually completed.

Comment: Linux can't read the drive and says it's encrypted so I do believe some files are still encrypted. When I initially encrypted it with Bitlocker over a year ago, I selected the "Encrypt full drive" option.

Comment: There could be a problem with the usb controller in the enclosure, I would see if you can remove the drive from the enclosure and connect it directly to the motherboard for decryption.

Comment: I'm able to read files, open photos/videos, add files and remove files from the drive. If the usb controller is faulty, why would bitlocker be affected but not those read/write operations? Bitlocker has also worked for two days and got up till 82.1%. Observation 3 also shows that bitlocker works fine with decrypting files until a certain point.

Comment: I hope you have a backup because it sounds like the HDD has failed.

Comment: Step 1a should be backing up your data. With that said, did you actually do a surface scan on the drive for bad sectors? Best to use the manufacturer’s diagnostic tool to perform a long test on the hard drive. Alternatively, you can use `chkdsk /r` or a tool like hddscan. You don’t know the drive is healthy until you’ve tested every sector on it.

Comment: I have started a "Long Generic" test on the drive from the manufacturer (Seagate) which I believe says it will take ~13 hours to complete. If that is successful, I'll run `chkdsk /r` on the drive. I'm currently trying to clear out some space on other drives to make room to backup the 1TB of unique data on the USB bitlocker drive

Comment: Managed to backup everything I needed to, the disk failed the manufacturer's diagnostic test "possibly caused by problem sectors which are difficult to read" and I have now started a "fix all long" repair.

Comment: The repair attempt from the manufacturer's tool failed, and I am now running `chkdsk /r`, and plan on running `chkdsk /F` once that completes.

Comment: Once again `chkdsk` found nothing, the manufacturer's tool cannot repair the drive, and Bitlocker is stuck at 82.1% decrypted. I'm going to try and borrow another 4TB drive and attempt `repair-bde`, and if that fails I'll try and copy as much information off the drive as possible and then format it.

Comment: Did you try a different USB enclosure? The controllers on these enclosures are critical ... under extremely heavy I/O the cheap ones can crap out. I know because of the Chia cryptocurrency, I spent a _lot_ of time testing those enclosures!

Comment: I have the same problem, my bitlocker drive decryption gets consistently stuck. I moved a SSD from a busted computer (bad PSU or motherboard, not sure which), so after I installed the same SSD on the new system, of course I had to enter my BitLocker recovery key. That worked fine, but I wasn't sure if I needed to re-encrypt the drive to make it fully compatible with the new mobo/TPM. So I started decrypting the drive, about 140gb of data on a 2TB Samsung 980 Pro SSD. It eventually got stuck, to the point that the system would be more or less unresponsive, **disk pegged at 100% usage**, sometim